# I got an android project written in scala - How can i open and work with this project in eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, scala, eclipse-plugin

I got an android project written in scala. How can I open and work with this project in eclipse? Which plugins do I need? Which scala compiler do I need? I just want to build a signed apk of the project.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7697153/scala-android-and-eclipse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check with these guys. Powerpoint and Video Links provided in the website.

http://www.swiftkey.net/en/blog/test-driven-development-on-android-using-native-scala-mocking-and-dependency-injection/

use Ant or SBT to compile:- (SBT plugin link)
https://github.com/jberkel/android-plugin

More links:-
http://days2011.scala-lang.org/node/138/291

Also read this about some issues with Scala v-2.9:-
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/scala-debate/El3QZEbIwHg

MISC:-
you can also try this methodology - 
Install Ubuntu on your device (as described here:- http://androlinux.com/android-ubuntu-development/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-android/). This will not affect the Android installation.

Boot Ubuntu, install JDK, Scala, etc, copy your Scala jars and run from there.